# test error and correlation

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, error, similarities

In my machine learning textbook, the most common way after applying a ML algorithm to a training set and test set is to compute the mean square error between your predictions and the response variable in the test set (in the case of regression). I was wondering, as an alternative, can one measure the correlation (or some similarity measure) between the test set response variable and the predicted set to gauge the accuracy of the model?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (like Ordinary least squares), you are assessing the correlation implicitly. The R square value is the square of the linear correlation (which measures the linear dependence) between your predicted and actual. 
You might notice that in the simple cases R square is related to MSE.
R^2 = 1 - SSE/(SSE + SS_Model)

Comment: Thanks for that. So, in my large dataset, my predicted values have a correlation to the response variable of 0.797, but my MSE is quite large. Can I still say my model is accurate?

Comment: MSE is not a normalized value, so whether that is large does not reveal the full story.

Comment: Ahh. So, if I just look at the correlation coefficient, which is 0.797, can I say my model has good predictive power? Thanks.

Comment: Generally you want to do a cross-validation, which means split your dataset into 5-10 fold, and evaluate your MSE in each fold and choose the best set of features based on the minimal test MSE (or there are other metrics like AIC,BIC, adjusted R2). I would say look at your R^2 for your training set, and if that's not a lot larger than (0.797^2) then the complexity of your model is ok. There is no absolute measure of predictive power and it all depends on the nature of the problem.

Comment: @Thomas Moore The correlation is not a pure measure of accuracy since it is affected by the MSE, slope, and the range of scores. That's why RMSE and the mean absolute error are better measures of accuracy per se.